# Find rolling 52 week high on daily stock market data in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

This seems like a simple question (and answer) but I'm having trouble with it.

The issue:

I have a pandas dataframe full of OHLC data. I want to find the rolling 52 week high throughout the dataframe.

My dataset is from yahoo.  You can pull the same data down with the folllowing code to get daily data:

```
import pandas.io.data as web
df = web.DataReader('SPX', 'yahoo', start, end)
```

A tail of the data gives the output below:

```
                 Open        High         Low       Close     Volume  
Date                                                                    
2016-07-15  216.779999  217.009995  215.309998  215.830002  107155400   
2016-07-18  215.970001  216.600006  215.669998  216.410004   58725900   
2016-07-19  215.919998  216.229996  215.630005  216.190002   54345700   
2016-07-20  216.190002  217.369995  216.190002  217.089996   58159500   
2016-07-21  216.960007  217.220001  215.750000  216.270004   66070000
```

To get the 52 week high (rolling), I can run the following:

```
df["52weekhigh"] = pd.rolling_max(df.High, window=200, min_periods=1)
```

I get the following (some col:

```
                 High  52weekhigh
Date                              
2016-07-15  217.009995  217.009995
2016-07-18  216.600006  217.009995
2016-07-19  216.229996  217.009995
2016-07-20  217.369995  217.369995
2016-07-21  217.220001  217.369995
```

This gives me an values for the 52 week highs as new highs come in, but I'm not a fan of using 200 here. Should it be 200 or 201 or 220 (there are "approximately" 200 trading days in the year)?

I could resample the data to weekly to get the values, but then i can't easily get back to my original daily data (or can I?).

So...here's the question:

Is there a way to run rolling_max on pandas dataframes and set the window to '52 weeks' or something similar? If not, can anyone think of a better approach to this than the above?

Comment: If you are having trouble use this instead `df["52weekhigh"] = df['Close'].rolling(window =200).max()` instead of `pd.rolling_max`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your data has business-day frequency then there should be roughly 5 rows per week. 
So 52 weeks would roughly correspond to `window=52*5`.

Of course, there might be a few other days missing due to holidays.  To be more
accurate, you could use `asfreq('D')` to change the frequency from business days
to actual days. Then you could use a rolling window of size `52*7`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
np.random.seed(2016)

N = 1000
index = pd.date_range('2000-1-1', periods=N, freq='B')
data = (np.random.random((N, 1))-0.5).cumsum(axis=0)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=index, columns=['price'])
# result = pd.rolling_max(df.asfreq('D'), window=52*7, min_periods=1)   # for older versions of Pandas
result = df.asfreq('D').rolling(window=52*7, min_periods=1).max()
result = result.rename(columns={'price':'rolling max'})

ax = df.plot()
result.plot(ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Way to go the extra mile with the plot :)

Comment: Thanks.  Can you help me understand how this is any different than just setting the window to 200 (or 252 or 356 or whatever other number I want)?

Comment: @EricD.Brown: The `window` parameter affects the number of *rows* included in
each calculation. If your DataFrame has exactly 5 business days for every week,
then a 52-week window would correspond exactly to `window=52*5`.  But if your DataFrame
skips some holidays (such as New Year's) then every week may not correspond to 5
days.  By using `asfreq('D')` to expand the frequency to days, you'll get one
row for every day. So you are *guaranteed* that 52 weeks corresponds exactly to
`window=52*7`.

Comment: One issue I recently discovered with `.asfreq('D')` is that it can potentially mess up the `datetime` values when daylight saving time kicks in. I was happily using the solution posted above until I realized that for long histories that span regular time and DST I was getting a lot of `NaN`s after the `.asfreq('D')` call.